# как можно заменить try/except

Tags: python, python-3.x

нужно сделать так чтобы код работал без try/except и при этом не давал вводить буквы и отрицательные числа

```
while True:
    try:
        a = float(input('Введите число ').replace(",", ".")[:3])
    except ValueError:
        print("Пожалуйста введите число")
        continue
    break
print(a)
```

Comment: а вот это `[:3]` зачем?

Comment: чтобы обрезать большие числа до 3х знаков

Comment: то есть, вас интересуют только первые три цифры числа, включая запятую? правильно?

Comment: да, все верно, но можно и больше

Comment: Ну проверяйте всё вручную тогда. Чтобы всё было `isdigit` либо точка (ну или запятая у вас)

Comment: я знаю что через isdigit можно сделать, но не знаю как

Comment: regex `(?=.*\d)\d*\.?\d*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isdigit = False
while not isdigit :
  a = input( 'Введите число ' )
  a = a.replace( ',', '.' )
  isdigit = True # предполагаем, что ввели число
  for char in a : # проверяем каждый символ
    if char not in [ *'0123456789.' ] :  
      isdigit = False
  if a.count( '.' ) > 1 :
      isdigit = False
print( a )
```

Comment: @min_4enko сегодня изучил метод a.isdecimal() он как раз возвращает True если строка содержит только числа. Хотя у тебя тут ещё и точка, а точка это не число

Answer (score 2):

```
def formDict():
    Dictionary_data = []
    for i in range(65, 92):
        Dictionary_data.append(chr(i))
    for i in range(97, 123):
        Dictionary_data.append(chr(i))
    for i in range(1040, 1104):
        Dictionary_data.append(chr(i))
    return Dictionary_data

dict_letter = formDict()
flag = False
while True:
    var = input('Введите число=')
    if var:
        flag = True
    for element in var:
        if element in dict_letter:
            flag = False
            print('Пожалуйста, введите число')
            break
    if flag:
        var = float(var.replace(",", "."))
        if var<0:
            flag = False
            print('Число не должно быть отрицательным!')
    if flag:
        break
print(var)
```

Либо более короткая запись, но тогда числа c запятой не пройдут:

```
flag = False
while True:
    var = input('Введите число=')
    if var:
        if var.isdigit():
            var = float(var.replace(",", "."))
        else:
            print('Пожалуйста, введите число')
        if flag:
            break
print(var)
```

@min_4enko, Ну или другой подход 1го варианта. Думаю самый подходящий:

```
dict_number = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
dict_number.extend([',','.'])
flag = False
while True:
    var = input('Введите число=')
    if var:
        flag = True
        for element in var:
            if element in dict_number:
                continue
            else:
                flag = False
                print('Пожалуйста, введите число')
                break
        if flag:
            var = float(var.replace(",", "."))
            break
print(var)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while True :
  a = input( 'Введите число ' )  
  if a.isdigit() :
    if int( a ) > 0 : # это число больше нуля
      break
  if a.replace( '.', '', 1 ) : # это число, а не строка    
    if float( a ) > 0 :
      break  
print( a )
```

Comment: есть проблема, при введении числа с плавающей точкой, он просит ввести число заново

Comment: @min_4enko а число с плавающей точкой тоже можно вводить ? Я думал что нельзя, только целые числа

Comment: а если введут две точки? А если введут два предложения из букв через точку?

Comment: @min_4enko всё же с конструкцией try будет короче, почему ты хочешь код именно без try ? Обрабатывать все возможные варианты будет достаточно сложно, а try обрабатывает сразу все возможные варианты

Comment: @Эникейщик согласен ! Как же тогда надо написать ? Чтобы работало и было без try ?

Comment: нужно написать код именно без try, так чтобы можно было ввести числа с плавающей точкой

Comment: @min_4enko я полностью переписал свою программу, и добавил ещё один вариант ответа. Теперь работает ! Ищи в ответах ещё один мой вариант. Количество точек я тоже проверил, пожалуйста, проверяй

Comment: спасибо, все работает, это как раз то что мне было нужно

Comment: @min_4enko ты его тогда отметь как решение, спасибо ! )

Comment: @min_4enko это такая зелёная галочка слева от ответа под строчками для голосования. Мой вариант начинается с isdigit = False

Comment: alex, можешь помочь?

Comment: @min_4enko что такое ? Напиши, что случилось

Comment: @alex, мы можем связаться какой нибудь соц. сети?

Comment: @min_4enko нет, пиши тут

Comment: в коде под которым мы сейчас общаемся выпадает ошибка "TypeError: must be real number, not str" , но это при добавлении каких либо операций по типу "a = a**2", можешь ли ты с этим помочь?

Comment: без доп операций все работает

Comment: @min_4enko оформляй новый вопрос, тут уже слишком много написано. Перепиши свой код снова, с нуля, и задай свой вопрос ( в отдельном задании )

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    a = input('Введите число ').replace(",", ".")[:3]
    q = "1234567890."
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(q)):
        for e in range(len(a)):
            if a[e] == q[i]:
                count += 1

    if count == len(a):
        break
    else:
        print("Пожалуйста введите число")
```

Comment: Ну это как-то неэффективно совсем. Можно просто же проверять `a[e] in q`, зачем лишний цикл.

Comment: Опять же, я введу все точки, и Ваша программа сломается.